# Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9 debug area warnings

Tags: ios, debugging, ios9, xcode7

I recently had my app approved by App review when I created it in Xcode 6.1 A few days ago I updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and with iOS 9 devices I got the following errors in debug area:

```
Oct 14 13:07:16  MonsterMAN[242] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

2015-10-14 13:07:33.735 MonsterMAN[242:8743] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterAuthenticateExtension invalidated

2015-10-14 13:07:53.385 MonsterMAN[242:8431] 13:07:53.381 WARNING:  [0x3ba4a000] 997: Failure to setup sound, err = -50

2015-10-14 13:08:04.272 MonsterMAN[242:8431] Received memory warning.

2015-10-14 13:39:20.607 MonsterMAN[265:13165] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterAuthenticateExtension invalidated

2015-10-14 13:39:25.027 MonsterMAN[265:13058] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x161d4400>)
plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated
```

How do I get rid of all of it?

Comment: have you tried setting your iOS deployment target  to iOS 8 or lower in your project settings?

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 7, always has been.